# Add github reminder message after committing files/before pushing

Tags: git, github, makefile, version-control, push

Is there a way I can customize/activate a reminder message to print to the terminal every time I commit files to git or before I push them.  I want a reminder message that says:

```
"make clean before pushing!"
```

I am working on a project with multiple users and we use `make` on different operating systems; if we don't make clean first, it's very easy to get out of sync with each other.

Comment: What for? `git push` doesn't push files, it pushes commits, and `make clean` doesn't clean commits.

Comment: Better yet, why don't you add the files to `.gitignore` so you _never_ accidentally push them?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. So you just need to show the message after committing changes?

Comment: That's a good idea, I could add them to git ignore.  Also I don't need make clean to clean a commit. I just wanted to remind myself to make clean and re-commit before pushing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the only way is, just check the condition of files.
By typing :

```
$ git status
```

I wish it can help you...